# What-dir reporting own directory as current directory in Rebol

Tags: linux, rebol

I am running Rebol on Debian Stable Linux and I have put rebol executable in /usr/local/bin. Then I have created following script file and also kept it in /usr/local/bin:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/rebol

REBOL []

print what-dir
quit
```

However, when I run this script from any directory, it only reports "/usr/local/bin/" and not current working directory. I want to get current working directory to perform operations from code.

Following code, using Linux shell command `pwd` (print working directory) also reports the same:

```
print call "pwd"
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: CALL automatically prints any output and returns the shell return code (`0` for success). If you want to capture output from CALL, you'll need to use CALL/OUTPUT: `trim/tail also out: make string! 60 call/output "pwd" out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your **own directory** where you are in **system/options/path** and if you want it to be your **current working directory** and **what-dir** to report your own directory as current directory, you have to add this line

```
system/script/path: system/options/path
```

or

```
change-dir system/options/path
```

before calling **what-dir**.

Even `call "pwd"` uses and shows now your own as current directory under Linux

Comment: But I want to get the directory from where it is run.

Comment: Did you check ?

Comment: Yes, it works. But `print call "pwd"` gives out only 0.

Comment: `call "pwd"` works but gives out only "\n" at end not "\r\n" . But `call/wait` works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this behaviour is quite unintuitive.

I came across the same situation a while ago, and I kept on making the same mistake over and over...  I eventually placed that `change-dir system/options/path` in a more general routines script, which is loaded from my `~/.rebol/view/user.r`.

Mind you though, one could also put that statement within the `user.r`.