# Getting different paths in Red language

Tags: path, rebol, red

I am trying to get different paths in Red language. If I cd to `/myfolder` and run following command:

```
/myfolder$ /path/to/red.exe /path/to/myscript.red
```

How can I get these 3 paths from code in script?

I tried:

```
system/options/path        ; Gives path/to/myscript
system/script/path         ; Gives none
call/output "pwd" outstr   ; Gives path/to/myscript
what-dir                   ; Gives path/to/myscript
```

I am able to get only one path. How can I get path of red.exe and path of current working directory (In Red language- not Rebol)?

Note: this is related to my question on Rebol at [What-dir reporting own directory as current directory in Rebol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461448/what-dir-reporting-own-directory-as-current-directory-in-rebol)

Answer (score 0):

In Rebol (2 & 3), this is how you can get those three paths:

```lisp
system/options/boot    ;; /path/to/red.exe
system/options/path    ;; /myfolder
system/script/path     ;; /path/to/myscript.red
```

At this moment only `system/options/boot` in Red matches what Rebol does here.

Answer (score 0):

From the GUI Console:

```
boot             string!       {C:\ProgramData\Red\gui-console-2017-11-30-4300.exe}
home             none!         none
path             file!         %/C/ProgramData/Red/
script           none!         none
cache            file!         %/C/ProgramData/Red/
```

From the cli:

```
boot             string!       "C:\ProgramData\Red\console-2017-11-30-4430.
home             none!         none
path             file!         %/C/Users/Old%20Man/desktop/
script           none!         none
cache            file!         %/C/ProgramData/Red/
```

Using the GUI Console:

```
system/options/boot   ; Red binary
system/options/path   ; current dir
system/options/cache  ; Red default dir "home"
```

system/options/boot is a `string!`, so you'll have to convert it with:

```
to-red-file system/options/boot
```